# Please help me understand the casue of error

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written a trigger with few SOQL queries at the start of code. Also i am avoiding SOQL queries in loops but still i am getting this exception error:

> System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

So can somebody please explain me how exactly i am crossing Soql limit of 100 ? Thanks in advance!..

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update, after insert) {

    List <Group> salesQueue        = [SELECT Id, name FROM Group WHERE type='Queue' And name != 'TCC Counsellors'];
    List<Calender__c > calList     = [SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Program__c, Intake_Month__c, Intake_Year__c FROM Calender__c WHERE Start_Date__c <= :System.Today() and End_Date__c >= :System.Today() ];
    Group queue                    = [SELECT Id, name FROM Group WHERE type='Queue' and Name='TCC Counsellors' Limit 1];
    List<GroupMember> queueMembers = [SELECT Group.Name, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId =: queue.Id ]; 
    integer val = 0;

    List<Lead> Exleads = [SELECT Id, name, email, MobilePhone, Program__c FROM Lead WHERE Id NOT IN : Trigger.new ];
    List <Duplicate_Lead__c> DupLeads = new List <Duplicate_Lead__c>();
    List<Lead> dupLeadsDelete = new List<Lead>();


    for( Lead ld : Trigger.new ) {

    if(Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
       /*Remove Company field value*/    
       if(ld.Company != null){ 
          ld.Company = null;  
       }

       /*Start - Set Assigned_to_Sales_Team value  */
       for( Group q : salesQueue){
          if(ld.OwnerId == q.Id && ld.Assigned_to_Sales_Team__c == false){  
           ld.Assigned_to_Sales_Team__c = true;
          }
       }
       /*End*/ 

       /*Start - FetchIntake */
       for( Calender__c cal : calList ) {

           if(Trigger.isInsert && ld.Program__c == cal.Program__c) {          
              ld.Intake__c        = cal.id;
              ld.Intake_Month__c  = cal.Intake_Month__c;
              ld.Intake_Year__c   = cal.Intake_Year__c;           
              //matchLead.add(le);            
           }   

        }
        /*End*/

        /*Start - FetchTccValues*/
        for (GroupMember qm :queueMembers  ) {
             if( ld.ownerid == queue.Id ) {
                 ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
                 ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = qm.Group.Name;
             } else if( ld.ownerid == qm.UserOrGroupId ) {
                 User us               = [SELECT Id,name FROM User where id =: qm.UserOrGroupId];
                 ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
                 ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = us.name;
             }
         }
        /*End*/

        /*Start - Lead Rating calculation*/
        if( ld.Program__c == 'EMBA' ) {

            if(ld.Work_Experience__c=='3 + years'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Qualification__c!='Undergraduate'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Lead_City__c=='Mumbai'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }

        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'DMM') {

             if(ld.Work_Experience__c=='0-3 years'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Qualification__c!='Undergraduate'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Program_Type__c=='PT' && ld.Lead_City__c=='Mumbai'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }  

        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'BDAP') {

            if(ld.Work_Experience__c=='5 + years'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Qualification__c=='Undergraduate or postgraduate degree in Engineering, Mathematics, Physics, Statistics, B.Sc, B.Pharma, BBA, Economics or Commerce'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Program_Type__c=='PT' && ld.Lead_City__c=='Mumbai'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }  

        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'MGB') {

            if(ld.Work_Experience__c=='0-3 years'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Qualification__c!='Undergraduate'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Test_Taken__c=='CAT'||ld.Test_Taken__c=='GMAT'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }

        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'GMBA') {

             if(ld.Work_Experience__c=='3 + years'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Qualification__c!='Undergraduate'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Test_Taken__c=='CAT'||ld.Test_Taken__c=='GMAT'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }      

        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'GFMB') {

            if(ld.Qualification__c!='Undergraduate'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Lead_City__c=='Mumbai'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }


        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'MgLuxM') {

            if(ld.Work_Experience__c=='0-3 years'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Qualification__c!='Undergraduate'){
                val=val+1;          
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }


        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'DBA') {

            if(ld.Work_Experience__c=='3 + years'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Qualification__c!='Undergraduate'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Lead_City__c=='Mumbai'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Test_Taken__c=='GRE'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }


        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'BBA'|| ld.Program__c == 'BBC' || ld.Program__c == 'BEC') {

            if(ld.Qualification__c=='Undergraduate'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }

        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'Cyber Security' || ld.Program__c == 'Machine Learning' || ld.Program__c == 'Virtual Reality') {

            if(ld.Work_Experience__c=='3 + years'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Qualification__c!='Undergraduate'&&ld.Qualification__c!='Graduate'&&ld.Qualification__c!='Post Graduate Diploma'&&ld.Qualification__c!='Masters Degree'&&ld.Qualification__c!='Undergraduate or postgraduate degree in Engineering, Mathematics, Physics, Statistics, B.Sc, B.Pharma, BBA, Economics or Commerce'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Lead_City__c=='Mumbai'||ld.Lead_City__c=='Bengaluru' ||ld.Lead_City__c=='Pune'||ld.Lead_City__c=='Chennai'||ld.Lead_City__c=='Trivandrum'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.LeadSource=='Walk In'||ld.LeadSource=='Incomming Call'||ld.LeadSource=='Chat'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Comfortable_with_Fee__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Info_session_Attended__c =='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_this_Intake__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Duplicacy__c==true){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_Program_For_Self__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }if(ld.Interested_in_SPJAT__c=='Yes'){
                val=val+1;
            }   

        }

    system.debug('Value of value variable:' + val);

        if( ld.Program__c == 'EMBA' ) {
            ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/10;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'DMM'&& ld.Program_Type__c=='PT') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/10;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'DMM'&& ld.Program_Type__c=='FT') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/9;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'BDAP'&& ld.Program_Type__c=='PT') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/10;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'BDAP'&& ld.Program_Type__c=='FT') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/9;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'MGB') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/10;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'GMBA') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/10;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'GFMB') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/9;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'MgLuxM') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/9;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'Cyber Security' || ld.Program__c == 'Machine Learning' || ld.Program__c == 'Virtual Reality') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/11;
        }else if(ld.Program__c == 'BBA'|| ld.Program__c == 'BBC' || ld.Program__c == 'BEC') {
             ld.Lead_Rating_Percentile__c = (((Double)val)*100)/10;
        }

      /*End*/

      /*Start Lead status update to Not Contacted when Lead goes from TCC to RM*/

       if( Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate ){
       Lead OldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(ld.Id);
         for (GroupMember qm :queueMembers  ) {
           if( (OldLead.Ownerid == qm.UserOrGroupId) && ld.ownerid != queue.Id && string.valueOf(ld.OwnerId).startsWith('00G') ) {
                 ld.Status = 'Not Contacted';
           }
         }      
       } 

     /*End*/ 

      /*Start - Updating custom fields for mapping with account*/

       if(ld.Status != null){
           ld.Hidden_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
       }
       if(ld.LeadSource != null){
           ld.Hidden_Lead_Source__c = ld.LeadSource;
       }
       if(true){
           ld.Hidden_Do_Not_Call__c = ld.DoNotCall;
           ld.Hidden_Partial_Application__c = ld.Partial_Application__c;
       } 

      /*End*/

    } // End  of Before trigger

     /*Start - After trigger for Lead Duplication*/

     if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
       for(Lead Ele : Exleads){

              if(( (ld.email != null && ld.email == Ele.email) && (ld.Program__c != null && ld.Program__c==Ele.Program__c) ) || ( (ld.MobilePhone != null && ld.MobilePhone == ELe.MobilePhone) && (ld.Program__c != null && ld.Program__c==Ele.Program__c) )){
              Duplicate_Lead__c DPLead = new Duplicate_Lead__c();

              DPLead.Name                = 'Duplicate Of'+' '+ Ele.Name;
              DPLead.Lead_Name__c        = ld.FirstName+ ' '+ld.LastName ;
              DPLead.Email__c            = ld.Email;
              DPLead.Mobile__c           = ld.MobilePhone;
              DPLead.Lead_Status__c      = ld.Status;
              DPLead.Lead_Source__c      = ld.LeadSource;
              DPLead.Work_Experience__c  = ld.Work_Experience__c;
              DPLead.program__c          = ld.Program__c;
              DPLead.Lead_City__c        = ld.Lead_City__c;
              DPLead.Lead_State__c       = ld.Lead_State__c;
              DPLead.Lead_Country__c     = ld.Lead_Country__c;


              Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];
              updLead.Duplicacy__c = true;
              Update updLead;

              DupLeads.add(DPLead);

              Lead leadDel = new Lead(Id=ld.Id);
              dupLeadsDelete.add(leadDel);

              }    
         }
       } 

     /*End*/


    } 

    if(!DupLeads.isEmpty()){
        Insert DupLeads;
     }

     if(!dupLeadsDelete.isEmpty()){
         Delete dupLeadsDelete;
     }


}
```

Comment: Avoid dml statements inside for loop. in your code `Update updLead;` is inside for loop

Comment: If you log `Exleads.size()`, what do you have ?

Comment: @user3486888, use the query outside the for loop , Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];
updLead.Duplicacy__c = true;
Update updLead; These statements should be written outside the for loop

Comment: Exleads.size() is number of existing leads which is in thousands

Comment: Ok so that the reason why you have this error. You did `for(Lead Ele : Exleads){ Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];`
Which produces more thant 100 queries in a loop !

Comment: You are correct ! thank you all for Pin pointing the error.... I am working on removing these mistakes..

Comment: Hi all,  1 question though:   Even if i have a DML and 1 SOQL inside a for loop both of these won't execute for all thousands of records.....as there is a if loop which will be true for only few records......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that you need to refactor is, try avoiding queries at start of the trigger, instead use advance for loop

for example

```
for(Account objAccount : [Select Id,Name From Account ]){
    //Do your manipulations
}
```

Which helps retrieving the records using queryMore

Second thing, Avoid DML inside For Loop and SOQL queries Inside for loops

```
  Afttected piece of code  
//Avoid Following
for(Lead Ele : Exleads){
  Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];
  updLead.Duplicacy__c = true;
  Update updLead;
}

 /*Start - FetchTccValues*/
    for (GroupMember qm :queueMembers  ) {
         if( ld.ownerid == queue.Id ) {
             ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
             ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = qm.Group.Name;
         } else if( ld.ownerid == qm.UserOrGroupId ) {
             **//Query Inside For Loop
             User us               = [SELECT Id,name FROM User where id =: qm.UserOrGroupId];**
             ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
             ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = us.name;
         }
     }
    /*End*/
//End

   /*Start - After trigger for Lead Duplication*/

  if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
 for(Lead Ele : Exleads){

      if(( (ld.email != null && ld.email == Ele.email) && (ld.Program__c != null && ld.Program__c==Ele.Program__c) ) || ( (ld.MobilePhone != null && ld.MobilePhone == ELe.MobilePhone) && (ld.Program__c != null && ld.Program__c==Ele.Program__c) )){
      Duplicate_Lead__c DPLead = new Duplicate_Lead__c();

      DPLead.Name                = 'Duplicate Of'+' '+ Ele.Name;
      DPLead.Lead_Name__c        = ld.FirstName+ ' '+ld.LastName ;
      DPLead.Email__c            = ld.Email;
      DPLead.Mobile__c           = ld.MobilePhone;
      DPLead.Lead_Status__c      = ld.Status;
      DPLead.Lead_Source__c      = ld.LeadSource;
      DPLead.Work_Experience__c  = ld.Work_Experience__c;
      DPLead.program__c          = ld.Program__c;
      DPLead.Lead_City__c        = ld.Lead_City__c;
      DPLead.Lead_State__c       = ld.Lead_State__c;
      DPLead.Lead_Country__c     = ld.Lead_Country__c;


      Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];
      updLead.Duplicacy__c = true;
      Update updLead;

      DupLeads.add(DPLead);

      Lead leadDel = new Lead(Id=ld.Id);
      dupLeadsDelete.add(leadDel);

      }    
 }
 }
```

/*End*/

You can refactor it as following

```
List<Lead> updateLeadList = new List<Lead>();
 for(Lead objLead : [select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id]){
    updLead.Duplicacy__c = true;
    updateLeadList.add(updLead);
 }

 try{
     update updateLeadList;
 }catch(Exception e){
 }
```

Thanks,
Nachiket

Comment: Hi Nachiket,  Thanks for prompt reply but the DML and Query are inside the IF loop which will be true only for few records mostly only 1 record then how come these statements are causing this exception.

Comment: Your If statement is within For loop (you are using Ele  object reference in Query just to highlight you)
for(Lead Ele : Exleads){
     Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];
}
suppose 200 records comes up then your query and dml statement will be executed 200 times, which will result in governor limit exceptions.

Comment: for(Lead Ele : Exleads){ //suppose exleads have 1000 records
              if(something){ This if condition will execute few times ideally only once. suppose this IF condtion is true 1 time
Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];  //this query will execute 1 time updLead.Duplicacy__c = true;
              Update updLead; //this DML will execute 1 time

              DupLeads.add(DPLead);

              Lead leadDel = new Lead(Id=ld.Id);
              dupLeadsDelete.add(leadDel);

              }    
         }
Am i correct?

Comment: I have removed both DML and SOQL statement outside the query but still getting the same error

Comment: please add the updated code in your question
Did you remove SOQL query from following Piece of code

Comment: for (GroupMember qm :queueMembers  ) {
         if( ld.ownerid == queue.Id ) {
             ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
             ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = qm.Group.Name;
         } else if( ld.ownerid == qm.UserOrGroupId ) {
             **//Query Inside For Loop
             User us               = [SELECT Id,name FROM User where id =: qm.UserOrGroupId];**
             ld.TCC_Lead_Status__c = ld.Status;
             ld.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = us.name;
         }
     }

Comment: Thanks for all the support..i have finally resolved the issue ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is within this part of the code :

```
 if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
       for(Lead Ele : Exleads){

              if(( (ld.email != null && ld.email == Ele.email) && (ld.Program__c != null && ld.Program__c==Ele.Program__c) ) || ( (ld.MobilePhone != null && ld.MobilePhone == ELe.MobilePhone) && (ld.Program__c != null && ld.Program__c==Ele.Program__c) )){
              Duplicate_Lead__c DPLead = new Duplicate_Lead__c();

              DPLead.Name                = 'Duplicate Of'+' '+ Ele.Name;
              DPLead.Lead_Name__c        = ld.FirstName+ ' '+ld.LastName ;
              DPLead.Email__c            = ld.Email;
              DPLead.Mobile__c           = ld.MobilePhone;
              DPLead.Lead_Status__c      = ld.Status;
              DPLead.Lead_Source__c      = ld.LeadSource;
              DPLead.Work_Experience__c  = ld.Work_Experience__c;
              DPLead.program__c          = ld.Program__c;
              DPLead.Lead_City__c        = ld.Lead_City__c;
              DPLead.Lead_State__c       = ld.Lead_State__c;
              DPLead.Lead_Country__c     = ld.Lead_Country__c;


              Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];
              updLead.Duplicacy__c = true;
              Update updLead;

              DupLeads.add(DPLead);

              Lead leadDel = new Lead(Id=ld.Id);
              dupLeadsDelete.add(leadDel);

              }    
         }
       }
```

As OP said in a comment

> Exleads.size() is number of existing leads which is in thousands

therefore this means that for each lead inside there he will be performing all the instructions inside the for bucle, included the query

```
 Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];
```

Therefore it will exceed the max limit of soql queries in a single execution context.

Also you have a dml operation inside a for bucle(update  updLead). Always avoid that (aswell as soql queries) since it could also make you exceep the dml operations limit. 
Here I attach you some tips&tricks to bulkify properly your code among with others. Hope this helps.

[Link Apex best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

EDIT:

Another thing you can modify is instead charging the Lead again with a new query, just use the one you're working with since you're just querying the same object you're handling.

Instead of using this:

```
Lead updLead=[select id from Lead where id = :Ele.id];
              updLead.Duplicacy__c = true;
              Update updLead;
```

Use this:

```
Ele.Duplicacy__c = true;
LeadsToUpdate.add(Ele);
```

And do the update after the for bucle for the whole thing. Obviously you should add Duplicacy to the query at the start but that should be enough.

Comment: Can you add . bit more explanation about why the update leads to the 101 queries error?

Comment: Just slipped there , modified adding a little more detail. Ty

Comment: Hi Alexander, 
Thanks for prompt reply but the DML and Query are inside the IF loop which will be true only for few records mostly only 1 record then how come these statements are causing this exception.

Comment: Hi , the thing is even if you put an IF inside a loop to try to control the number of objects that make you enter there it's not a good practice. 

Instead you should query before the for bucle, store it inside a map and get the objects from that map instead. That way you avoid any possible way of using additional queries.

Map<id,Lead> mapLeads = new Map<id,Lead> ([SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE id in: Insert_set/map.keyset name_here]);

And the use a getter inside the for loop. 

Nachiket Deshpande explained pretty well on the answer to your comment.

Comment: I edited my answer with more info, tell me if that helps you.

Comment: I have removed both DML and SOQL statement outside the query but still getting the same error

Comment: Then it's due some other Trigger code probably also increasing a lot your SOQL queries, as I explained on the other post. Put some System.debug() statements to track down how many soql queries each trigger is doing and then find where lies the problem.

Also take into account that some triggers may cause recursive calls that may increase also that number of queries.

Comment: I don't get it...trigger works fine but when i use test class it gives me this error. I will try to use debug statements of find where queries are getting used.    Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Are you using Test.StartTest() and Test.stopTest() ? If you're not You should sorround the code that will trigger your code by this clauses so you can isolate the context from the other queries you may be doing on your test class + on the triggers that could be triggering before when you are inserting data.

Comment: Thanks for all the support..i have finally resolved the issue ;)