# Can below scenario cause: Too many SOQL queries 101 exception?

Tags: apex, unit-test, governorlimits

```
for (Lead ObLeads : ListOfLead){
    if(condition){
        1 SOQL query;
        1 DML statement;
     }
}
```

Here `ListOfLead` has 500 records and condition will be true only for 1 Lead record. So in this scenario can this code generate Too many SOQL queries 101 exception? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is relate to your other [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154239/please-help-me-understand-the-casue-of-error/154241?noredirect=1#comment226449_154241)

As Santanu said, no, it won't trigger that exception by itself.

The thing is that when you are doing this operation take note that also you are updating a Lead and therefore triggering Lead triggers before update / after update. They are in the same execution context than your code and therefore you should also take count of all the SOQL operations that are generated in any subsequent codes you call from there. 
And same applies otherwise, if this was triggered by a DML operation you should take into account that all other queries&DML operations done in the same execution context will remain till the end of it. So maybe isn't just this piece of code that exceeds it but the whole context.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is that you are not centering your thinking around ***collections***. You're still working with single records. So you're not really working with the platform in the way it was designed when you code this way.

While you are correct that if your assumption holds, you will only execute these operations once, your assumption could be plain wrong, or be invalidated down the road. I recommend you instead adopt **filters** so that you can build your approach around ***collections***. This way, even if you know for certain sure that there should only be one record to act on, you still don't risk operations in a loop that shouldn't be there.

```
List<Lead> leadsToActOn = new List<Lead>();
for (Lead record : allRecords)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        leadsToActOn.add(record);
    }
}
// SOQL
// DML
```

If you adopt this approach, you can really improve your **`Separation Of Concerns`**, because almost every action you take has these two components: `Filter` and `Action`. You may notice that `Workflow Rules` and `Process Builder` break logic down in a similar manner, so it shouldn't be a huge adjustment.

One extra benefit is that there is a great library already out there to do this sort of filtering for you called [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector).

Answer (score 1):

No it will not encounter the `'Too many SOQL queries 101 exception'` exception provided you don't have 99 others SOQLs running in the same transaction from other places and this includes the trigger if there is any which will get fired due to the DML. :)

However as the best practice you should fire your SOQL queries either before or after the for loop and hold the result in a List or set and re-use wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

The key part in your code is the "**if condition**".  If that condition satisfies for "more than 100 leads" in the list `ListofLead`, then it would cause the error. Because you mentioned that your `if` condition satisfies for only 1 lead, you are safe for now.

However, I suggest, as a best practice, do NOT include a SOQL/DML statement inside a `for` loop.